# Line integrals of the vector field $F(x,y)=\left( \frac{y}{x^2 + 4y^2}, \frac{-x}{x^2 + 4y^2}+z, \ y\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Given the vector field $F(x,y)=\left( \dfrac{y}{x^2 + 4y^2}, \dfrac{-x}{x^2 + 4y^2}+z, y\right)$

Let's consider the points $A=(2,1,1) \ B=(1,1,0) \ C=(0,1,0)$ and $D=(0,1,1)$

Calculate the following line integrals

$1)$ $$\int_{AD} \vec{F}d \vec{r}$$

$2)$ $$\int_{ABCDA} \vec{F}d \vec{r}$$

$3)$ $$\int_{DBCA} \vec{F}d \vec{r}$$

We denote *AD* to the curve that joins *A* with *D*.
In the same way we denote *ABCDA* to the curve that joins *A* with *B*, *B* with *C*, *C* with *D* and *D* with *A*. (same with *DBCA* curve)

I suspect that this exercise should be done by applying properties of conservative fields. The curl of $ \vec F$ is zero but $ \vec F$ doesn't have a simply connected domain so I don't know if it is a conservative field. I tried to find a potential function that I will call $U$ such that $ \nabla U= \vec F$ but I couldn't get it so I can't conclude if $ \vec F$ is a conservative field so I don't know how to solve those line integrals.

Comment: The points $A,B,C$ and $D$ and all connecting lines between them lie in the half-space $x+y>\frac{1}{2}$, which is a convex, simpy connected subset of the domain of $\vec F$, where $\vec F$ is thus a conservative vector field. So the _closed_ integral $(2)$ should be zero. The other integrals I suspect you should calculate by plugging in the definition of the line integral until you're left with a simple one-dimensional integral. You could also go looking for a potential $U$ defined only on this half-plane.

Comment: Consider the potential $\phi = -\arg(x + 2 i y)/2 + y z$ with $\arg$ taking values in $(-\pi, \pi]$. Also, the gradient theorem doesn't require the domain to be simply connected.

Comment: As there is a potential then $ \vec F$ is conservative field?

Comment: Why  the points $A,  B ,  C$ and $D$ are in the half-space $x+y > \dfrac{1}{2}$ @JosefE.Greilhuber